# convert a date string to datetime compatible to postgresql

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgresql, datetime

I have a date string in the format,

```
"dd/mm/yyyy"
e.g="23/2/2017"
```

How can I convert this to a valid format, so that I can save this value in Datetime field of postgresql.

I tried using datetime package, but not getting.

Comment: postgres does not have "Datetime field of postgresql" - please show the exact command and error

Comment: This is in Postgresql,

valid_from_date -  timestamp with time zone 

And in Django Model file, I am writing,

valid_from_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

Comment: to answer your question I need the output of `show datestyle` on your db

Answer (score 9):

in Postgres you can "adjust" your datestyle, eg:

```
t=# set datestyle TO DMY;
SET
Time: 0.215 ms
t=# select '23/2/2017'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2017-02-23 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

or just "parse" with right mask (ignoring not suitable datestyle), eg:

```
t=# select to_timestamp('23/2/2017','DD/MM/YYYY');
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2017-02-23 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <columnname> TYPE DATE using to_date(<columnname>, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```